# How to perform this conda operation on Windows

Tags: python, conda, environment

I am trying to create a conda environment based on a requirements.txt file.  This file has been given to me and I may not change it or reproduce.

I am trying to use this file to create the exact same environment. I have found a solution on this [page](https://www.technologyscout.net/2017/11/how-to-install-dependencies-from-a-requirements-txt-file-with-conda/):

> Just a little reminder: pip has this very useful option to install a
>   bunch of packages from a single text file mostly called
>   requirements.txt. Anaconda’s command line tool conda doesn’t support
>   this option directly. It does support reading the package names from a
>   file using the –yes and –file option
>
> `conda install --yes --file requirements.txt`
>
> but that does not automatically install all the dependencies. To do
>   this, we need to iterate over the file and install each package in
>   “single package mode”:
>
> `while read requirement; do conda install --yes $requirement; done <
>   requirements.txt`

However I am unable to translate it into windows 10 bash code:

```
for %%F IN requirements.txt DO conda install --yes
```

also tried

Comment: can you try `conda env create -f requirement.txt`

Comment: I thhink you are only missing putting the actual file line in the body of that loop: `for %%F IN requirements.txt DO conda install --yes %%F`. But specifying the file when creating the env is more straight forward

Comment: I think that in conda I can't specify the file at creation unless it is a `.yaml`